# Can anyone help me with the following error i am facing while creating a Dapp social media application?

Tags: next.js, error-handling, blockchain

[this is the error i am facing, this is in the upload modal of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQdtY.png)

i want this modal to upload the pics as new post on my Dapp social media platform. it showing something like a sdk update and redirecting me to a bytesscale.com and asking for subs fee

Comment: The error says you should upgrade to the latest version of the SDK. Do so, then the error should resolve itself.